# very small number values in anychart cause graph to crash (OOM)

Tags: anychart

When i am trying to plot some trading data with very small precision such as below the graph keeps crashing in Chrome.

e.g data

```
[{
    last: 0.00000009,
    epoch: 1519242003170
  },
  {
    last: 0.00000009,
    epoch: 1519242006022
  }, 
  ...
]
```

This is an example where it works OK.. https://playground.anychart.com/kmc20SIB

But this one will crash when i run it.. https://playground.anychart.com/9g02XjOO/1

The only difference is i added one more data set item with

```
last: 0.00000010,
```

Is this a bug with very small numbers, mem leak or something ? I tried in FireFox and it seems to crash also with `uncaught exception: out of memory`.

Also when this is working/fixed.. can you tell me how best to display these very small numbers on the graph? When i'm using `0.00000009` the y-axis goes in steps of `0, 0.3, 0.6` which is useless.

Many thanks

Comment: We are planning to provide the fix with future updates.
As a temporary workaround, I can suggest you the following solution. You can cut off decimal in your dataset and add the exponent to all labels (use scientific notation). For example, your value is '2.63e-6' – use the following instead – '2.63' and then add 'e-6' in all labels. This will allow avoiding this bug.
There's a template to show how it works and looks like here -
https://playground.anychart.com/TI8L6uLV

Comment: Reverting back to version 8.0.1 should fix the issue until there is a fix for the latest version. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your report! It seems to be a bug, we will investigate this issue and provide a solution or ETA for the fix. It may take us some time, but we will update when we get new information.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue with candlestick stock charts when passing small values like 0.00002222 . Reverting back to v8.0.1 of anychart fixed the issue for me.

Some others reported a the same issue here if you want to keep track of the issue. https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart/issues/42

Answer (score 0):

We glad to notify you that the fix for your issue is available with the 8.3.0 version update. Please, update your AnyChart binaries to get the fix. You can download all required binaries using our CDN - https://www.anychart.com/download/cdn/?v=8.3.0